# Apache Fineract Reporting

Tags: pentaho, apache-fineract

I have got Apache fineract(Open Source core banking solution) from GitHub, So it is a gradle-based project, All functionality works well, But In reporting section, when I want to get a report by using Pentaho, I got this exception "org.apache.fineract.infrastructure.core.exception.PlatformServiceUnavailableException, Message: There is no ReportingProcessService registered in the ReportingProcessServiceProvider for this report type: Pentaho".
Anyone can help me to solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you should add manually `PentahoReportingProcessServiceImpl` that stays in [fineract pentaho](https://github.com/openMF/fineract-pentaho) to your code base.

secound of all add the pentaho reporting dependencies to your dependecies.gradle.(find them in the [fineract pentaho](https://github.com/openMF/fineract-pentaho))

finally add the following lines to build.gradle

```
repositories {
maven {
    url "https://mifos.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local"
}
maven {
    url "https://repo.orl.eng.hitachivantara.com/artifactory/pnt-mvn/"
}
mavenCentral()}
```